# Bootstrap align div correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set 2 div elements next to each other by using bootstrap
code:

```
<div class='col-12'>

    <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-6'>
         </div>

         <div class='col-6'>
         </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

this works fine the only thing is that when the window width gets to small
the divs overlap. when it gets to small I want to set the divs beneath each other
and col-6 then has to be col-12

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should read the document about grid system. And chose which size you want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sm` breakpoint...

https://www.codeply.com/go/QGmvcPu7Ts

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-sm-6'>
         </div>
         <div class='col-sm-6'>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they are still overlapping

Answer (score -1):

You should use have read the [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to make them align in every screen width.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='col-12'>

    <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12'>
          lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM 
         </div>

         <div class='col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12'>
         lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM lOREM ePSUM 
         </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: xs does not exsit in bootstrap 4

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class='col-12'>
    <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-6 col-xs-12'>
         </div>
         <div class='col-6 col-xs-12'>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col-xs` no longer available in Bootstrap 4.
Based on the question code, he's using Bootstrap 4

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.